# Having trouble accessing Sharepoint server but only in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint

We have a client we're trying to do work for at my company - they have a Sharepoint server setup.

We keep trying to access it, and are having no problems in Chrome or Firefox, however when we try to access it in IE (to edit files) - it keeps requesting authentication credentials. Even when we put the correct ones in, it doesn't save them, it just keeps prompting.

I've tried clearing all of my credentials, I've tried adding the domain to my trusted sites in IE - what else can I do to fix this?

Comment: Does it do this from ANY IE machine or just one?

Comment: EVERY IE machine, every IE version that we've tested on.

Comment: Related over on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002716/sharepoint-popup-login-windows